# Using the boolean value from appdelgate all across app

Tags: ios, boolean, appdelegate

In my app I need to check whether a user already exists or not and need to update accordingly. In order to achieve this I have created a boolean in **appdelegate.h** and accessed it all across the app. I need to do

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)AppDelegate*appDelegate;  
appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

in **view did load** of every controller where I wanted to change the boolean value. In order to reduce my coding I did following in the **appdelegate.h**:

In appdelegate.h I have created a constant APPDELEGATE which would refer to app delegate obj. Now using which I have defined EXISTING_USER as the boolean which is constant of shared application can be used across app.

```
#define APPDELEGATE (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
#define EXISTING_USER [APPDELEGATE existingUserUpdate]  
@property (nonatomic ,readonly) bool existingUserUpdate;
```

In this format of declaring EXISTING_USER, I can only access it, but I'm unable to alter its value. Is there any way I would alter the boolean value in required view controllers using this sort of approach? Or I need to stick with the previous code like declaring app delegate obj in **view did load** method of every view controller?

Comment: Why are you storing data in the app delegate in the first place?

Comment: You should avoid storing 'Globals' on the app delegate. It really isn't the place for this kind of thing. If you must have some widely accessible variable or value either define it as a constant (immutable) or have it Managed by a service or manager. Using the app delegate for this kind of thing is very messy :(.

Comment: No I'm storing data in AppDelegate, I was just creating a boolean variable in AppDelegate ,so that i can access it else where in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple class to track the user's status, and by using singletone you can access it from anywhere in the app.

SGUser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SGUser : NSObject
+ (SGUser *) activeUser;
@property BOOL loggedIn;
@end
```

SGUser.m

```
#import "SGUser.h"

@implementation SGUser

+ (SGUser *) activeUser {
    static SGUser *activeUser = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        activeUser = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return activeUser;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _loggedIn = false;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And then from any part of your code you can easily call.

```
[[SGUser activeUser] setLoggedIn:true];
[[SGUser activeUser] loggedIn];
```

Answer (score 1):

The app delegate is not the place to store shared data, you should have a specific (probably singleton) class for this.

But, in order to change the value you can do the following:

```
APPDELEGATE.existingUserUpdate = YES;
```

Good luck.

Comment: I agree, lightweight singleton classes should be used for these kind of things

Comment: I tried doing APPDELEGATE.existingUserUpdate = YES; but it says "assigning to 'read-only 'return result of an objective-c message not allowed".  :(

Comment: That is because you added the 'readonly' flag to the property!

Comment: well I now removed the property readOnly still dot notation is working besides      [APPDELEGATE setExistingUserUpdate:YES]; this is working for me.thanks for your support @Yedidya

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use NSUserDefaults?

Like,

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
[defaults setBool: YES forKey : @"USER_EXISTENCE"];
```

And use it everywhere you like...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
BOOL userExistance = [defaults boolForKey : @"USER_EXISTENCE"];
```

Let me know if this works, or you still have issues..

Comment: The NSUserDefault is not for storing share data while the app is running, it should be used for saving data when the app is terminated. If you decide to use it (it will work) you need to add the '[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];' function in order to save the data Immediately (it will insert the data to the user default file Synchronously).

Comment: The existence of the logged in user would matter even after the applications is terminated, wouldnt it?

Comment: @Mayur Deshmukh  using NSUserDeafault will also serve my purpose.I checked it this also works fine as of needed purpose in my present app. Thanks.

Comment: And as I feel that loggedInUser's existence is a propert of the application, I think is should be persisted in NSUserDefaults. Though you can use Mr.Me's solution and persist it in the getters and setters